# English equivalent of "to not scratch one's ear on something"

Tags: expressions, idioms, idiom-requests

We have an idiom in Urdu language which translates to:

**Translation into English:** I don't/won't scratch/rub my ear on that.

**Meaning:** We use it to mean "I will just ignore this because it does not interest me or it is dull or I do not take it seriously".

Example sentence: My friend A told me something that was annoying and another friend (B) heard it. Then after some time, B privately told me not to get angry or upset about what A said, I said "I do not scratch my ear on that" (I don't take it seriously and will ignore it).

I know it is confusing but if there is any English idiom with any of its meaning, please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent phrase to: "tell it to the marines"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/472913/equivalent-phrase-to-tell-it-to-the-marines)

Comment: I do not suggest this as anything like a literal translation, and that reads as though it means something as simple as "I wouldn't waste my time…"

A strong idiom might be "I wouldn't give a rat's whisker" and that's a polite version.

Answer (score 1):

One idiom that might suit this situation is "It's like water off a duck's back." Here is the entry for that expression in Christine Ammer, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms*, second edition (2013):

> **like water off a duck's back** Readily and without apparent effect. For example, *The scathing reviews rolled off him like water off a duck's back*. This expression alludes to the fact that duck feathers shed water. {Early 1800s}

Another water-related idiom that might suit the occasion is "It's water under the bridge." Here is Ammer on that idiom:

> **water over the dam** Also, **water under the bridge** Something that is obver and done with, especially an unfortunate occurrence. For example, *Last year's problem with delivery are water over the dam*, or *Never mind that old quarrel; that's water under the bridge*. These metaphoric phrases allude to water that has flowed over a spillway or under a bridge  and thus us gone forever. The first term was recorded  in 1979; the variant dates from the late 1800s.

And a third potentially relevant idiom (suggested in a now-deleted answer to this question by Kaycee) is "It went in one ear and out the other." Again, from Ammer:

> **in one ear and out the other** Quickly forgotten, as in *Their advice to her just went in one ear and out the other*. This expression, a proverb in John Heywood's 1546 collection, conjures up  a graphic image of sound traveling through one's head. {Late 1300s}

English also has many idiomatic ways of saying that a person is not going to let some minor unpleasantness or annoyance become a long-term problem or concern: "I won't let it weigh [or prey] om my mind"; "I won't stew about it"; "It's no big deal"; "It's already in the rear-view mirror"; "I've already moved on from that"; "Life is too short [to hold grudges over something so minor]"; "I don't sweat the small [or petty] stuff"; etc.

Answer (score 0):

Expressions rooted in the implication of "not caring" may nicely substitute for your pattern :

- I couldn't care less!
- I don't care a fig/a pap/a pin/a continental/a copper/a dime/a wit/a scrap!
- See if I care!

Idioms stemming from the verb "to take" will also be helpful to convey the idea that you don't take it seriously:

- I don't give a hoot/a damn/a crap/a toss!
- not to give a monkey's (To be honest I don't give a monkey's what he said).

Formulae with intentional wrench of grammar rules may also suit well: "It don't make me no never mind" etc.

Some more idioms:

- Bollocks to that!
- It's no skin off my nose/teeth/back!
- I should worry!
- Who cares a rap?

Answer (score 0):

A similar idiom that is *without disdain* and that also refers to the face is

> I wouldn't **bat an eye(lid)**.

**bat an eye(lid)**

> To react in any slight way; to respond. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bat_an_eyelid#English)

> Show no surprise or concern. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/not_bat_an_eye)